# MPI Sending array of array

Tags: c, mpi, mpich

ok so I am trying to send a structure like so over MPI

```
struct BColumns {
        double **B;
        int offset;
};
```

And if I just do some BS allocation of data like so

```
    bSet.offset = myRank;
    bSet.B = (double **) calloc(2, sizeof(double *));
    bSet.B[0] = (double *) calloc(1, sizeof(double));
    bSet.B[1] = (double *) calloc(1, sizeof(double));

    bSet.B[0][0] = 1;
    bSet.B[1][0] = 2;


    if(myRank == 0){
            MPI_Send(&bSet,sizeof(struct BColumns), MPI_BYTE, 1, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }else{
            MPI_Recv(&recvBuf, sizeof(struct BColumns), MPI_BYTE, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status );
    }
```

And I am assuming that its not going to work well because if I send this structure as is it will just send the pointer in B and that pointer doesn't point to anything on the other processor, so how would I go about sending data like this in MPI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suszterpatt points out, you really want to allocate your block of `B` in one big chunk; that's probably better for performance anyway but it's really required for any communications so you're not chasing pointers everywhere.  And I think one way or another you're probably going to have to do it in different sends -- sending size information, then the data in one chunk -- although you could probably create and delete a different MPI_Type_struct for every one of these you send.  But using multiple sends per object isn't very hard:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

typedef struct BColumns {
        double **B;
        int offset;
} bc;

double **alloc2d(int n, int m) {
    double *data = malloc(n*m*sizeof(double));
    double **array = malloc(n*sizeof(double *));
    for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
        array[i] = &(data[i*m]);
    }
    return array;
}

void free2d(double **array) {
    free(array[0]);
    free(array);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    const int tag = 13;
    int size, rank;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    if (size < 2) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Requires at least two processes.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    if (rank == 0) {
        int ncols=3, colsize=5;
        bc *send;

        send = malloc(sizeof(bc));
        send->offset = 1;
        send->B = alloc2d(ncols, colsize);
        for (int i=0; i<ncols; i++)
            for (int j=0; j<colsize; j++)
                send->B[i][j] = i*j;

        const int dest = 1;
        MPI_Send(&ncols,   1, MPI_INT, dest, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&colsize, 1, MPI_INT, dest, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&(send->offset), 1, MPI_INT, dest, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Send(&(send->B[0][0]), ncols*colsize, MPI_DOUBLE, dest, tag,
                 MPI_COMM_WORLD);


        printf("Rank %d: sent structure B\n", rank);
        free2d(send->B);
        free(send);
    }

    if (rank == 1) {
        MPI_Status status;
        const int src=0;
        int rncols, rcolsize;
        bc *recv;

        MPI_Recv(&rncols,   1, MPI_INT, src, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&rcolsize, 1, MPI_INT, src, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        printf("Rank %d: Received: rncols = %d rcolsize=%d\n", rank, rncols, rcolsize);

        recv = malloc(sizeof(bc));
        recv->B = alloc2d(rncols, rcolsize);

        MPI_Recv(&(recv->offset), 1, MPI_INT, src, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&(recv->B[0][0]), rncols*rcolsize, MPI_DOUBLE, src, tag,
                MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);

        printf("Rank %d: Received: offset = %d\n", rank, recv->offset);
        for (int i=0; i<rncols; i++) {
            printf("%d:  Column %d/%d: ", rank, i, rncols);
            for (int j=0; j<rcolsize; j++)
                printf(" %lf ", recv->B[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }

        free2d(recv->B);
        free(recv);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

And then running it:

```
$ mpirun -np 3 ./bstruct
Rank 0: sent structure B
Rank 1: Received: rncols = 3 rcolsize=5
Rank 1: Received: offset = 1
1:  Column 0/3:  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000 
1:  Column 1/3:  0.000000  1.000000  2.000000  3.000000  4.000000 
1:  Column 2/3:  0.000000  2.000000  4.000000  6.000000  8.000000
```

You could marshall  that data into one message if you wanted to avoid the latency of several sends (and if you knew before hand a maximum size for the B array) either by hand or using MPI function calls or data types, but you'd still have to do it in a similar way.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to use a single array to store your values in row/column-major order, so that it's all contiguous in memory. Then you just need to define an MPI datatype that describes the struct's memory layout (lots of doubles and an int).

Comment: So now what about if I don't have a set size for this array so I still need a pointer in the structure and I dynamically allocate the array, even if I do put it in row/column major I would still be passing a pointer that doesn't have any meaning to the other process.

Comment: And for that reason, you wouldn't be sending the struct itself. Instead, send the data from which the receiving process can rebuild the same struct: the array of doubles and the int. The principle will be the same, though you'll have to make clever use of the `MPI_Address` function, and ensure that either the relative position of the doubles and the int in memory doesn't change, or that you redefine the datatype after it has changed. Or just pass multiple messages.